# Remove Azure AD B2C Local Account all Users using Azure portal or PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

We have 1000 Azure AD B2C local User. Need to truncate all users from it. What is the best way to delete all users from Azure AD B2c

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **MSOnline** PowerShell module (or the new **AzureAD** module) to do that. Example:

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-Msoluser | Remove-Msoluser
```

Comment: Add -All to the Get-MsolUser call, otherwise this will only delete the first X (100?) users